# Как обратиться к элементу кортежа, который является значением словаря Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, кортежи

Есть словарь видов тренировки, его ключами являются коды видов тренировок, его значениями - кортеж из класса тренировки и числа полей (для каждого класса оно своё).
Задача: при несоответствии числа полей "на входе" заданному в классе выдавать предупреждение. Для этого необходимо сравнить число полей "на входе" с числом полей, заданным в каждом классе, то есть, получается, что нужно обратиться ко второму элементу кортежа, который является значением словаря.

```
WORKOUT_TYPES = {'SWM': (Swimming, len(dataclasses.fields(Swimming))),
                 'RUN': (Running, len(dataclasses.fields(Running))),
                 'WLK': (SportsWalking, len(dataclasses.fields(SportsWalking)))}

def read_package(workout_type: str, data: dict) -> Training:
    if workout_type not in WORKOUT_TYPES:
        raise ValueError(REPORT_TRAINING_ERROR.format(workout_type)) 
    if len(data) != WORKOUT_TYPES[workout_type]:
        raise ValueError(REPORT_DATA_ERROR.format(workout_type,
                         len(data), WORKOUT_TYPES[workout_type]))
    return  WORKOUT_TYPES[workout_type](*data)
```

Заранее всех благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы обратится к элементу кортежа, нужно указать в квадратных скобках его индекс.

То есть если у вас сам кортеж `WORKOUT_TYPES[workout_type]`, то к его второму элементу можно обратится так: `WORKOUT_TYPES[workout_type][1]`

Впрочем, когда в коде идёт такое обращение по чиселкам, то становится сложно читать и понимать этот код. Можно заменить простой кортеж на именованный и тогда к его полям можно будет обращаться по понятным именам. Например так:

```
from collections import namedtuple

WtMeta = namedtuple('WtMeta', 'cls, fields_num')

WORKOUT_TYPES = {
    'SWM': WtMeta(
               Swimming, len(dataclasses.fields(Swimming))
           ),
    'RUN': WtMeta(
               Running, len(dataclasses.fields(Running))
           ),
    'WLK': WtMeta(
               SportsWalking, len(dataclasses.fields(SportsWalking))
           ),
}

print( WORKOUT_TYPES['RUN'].fields_num )    # Вот так вот
```

Впрочем, в данном случае вообще не понятно, зачем вам отдельно хранить количество полей рядом с классом, если вы просто в любом месте можете взять класс и дёрнуть для него `len(dataclasses.fields(...))`. Так вам не нужно будет хранить кортеж, достаточно будет только хранить один класс, и код станет проще.